# How to catch the exception when set form group control in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a form group.

```
@Input() readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder;
public myFormGroup :FormGroup;
this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({name: null});
```

Then in somewhere I want to patch the value by the code.

```
try {
    this.myFormControl.controls.name.setValue('some value');
} catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
}
```

However it failed to set up the value. My question is that I can't catch the error. In the debugging I found it went to `Subscriber.js` and method

```
SafeSubscribe.prototype._tryOrUnsub = function(fn ,value) {
  try {
    fn.call(this._context, value); // hover it shows value = undefined
 }
   catch (err) {
   this.unsubscribe();
   throw err;
  }
};
```

So I still don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out by myself
The control is a `kendo-datepicker`; it need to convert a format then it works.

```
<kendo-datepicker [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'" formControlName = "name"></kendo-datepicker>
```

And the ts code

```
this.myFormControl.controls.name.setValue(new Date('some value));
```

So the trick is to add `new Date()`.

But why I could not catch the error I still don't know. For the moment it works out now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating via

```
this.myFormControl.controls.get('name').setValue('some value');
```

where 'name' is the name of your formcontrol.

Also when it comes to debugging, go ahead and add in the word `debugger;` right before you call the code that you think produces the error. It will cause chrome to stop execution and bring up a javascript debugger in devtools. It may help you diagnose your problems.